# How do you get the value from a data-frame using the index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
test      data
 1         11
 1         12
 1         0
 1         15
 1         16
 1         0
```

So here I am trying to get the value which is before the `0`

```
    zero_indexes = list(input_with[input_with['data'] == 0].index)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    for each_zero_index in zero_indexes:
       value = input_with.loc[each_zero_index - 1: each_zero_index]
        if(value != 0):
              df1 = input_csv.loc[each_zero_index - 3: each_zero_index]
              df2 = df2.append(df1) 
df2.to_csv('final_2.csv')
```

Here, I am not getting the `value` as it is only returning `df`. Can Someone help me with this?

Comment: What does your expected output look like?  A list?

Comment: Actually, In return I don't want to have the dataframe. it should be only 12 in first iteration, in second it will 16 like that  . Only number value so that I can check it weather it is not equal to zero or not

Answer (score 4):

IIUC you can use:

```
df.loc[df.data.eq(0).shift(-1).fillna(False), 'data']

1    12
4    16
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

---

Update based on your comment:

```
df.loc[df.data.eq(0).shift(-1).astype(bool).idxmax(), 'data']
# 12
```

Comment: Actually, In return I don't want to have the dataframe. it should be only 12 in first iteration, in second it will 16 like that

Comment: Why not `df[df['data'].shift(-1).eq(0)]` ?

Comment: Hey, your answer is correct but here ,I want to take this from the for loop, so that I used  [0] here. Now I am getting , but  input_csv.loc[each_zero_index - 3: each_zero_index]  this line is adding the 0 value also in the dataframe. I want only previous three values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to get the values from 'data' column which are non-zero OR, get values up to first zero in 'data' column?

This appends the non-zero values on a new DataFrame if that is what you want :

```
index=data.index[data['data'] != 0].tolist()
print(index)
data2=pd.DataFrame([])
for i in index:
    x=data.loc[i,'test']
    y=data.loc[i,'data']
    df=pd.DataFrame({'test':[x],
                     'data':[y]})
    data2=data2.append(df,ignore_index=True)
print(data2)
```